# Why response .then from axios can't change value of variable

Tags: express, axios

```
const axios = require('axios');
const url = '';
const urlMovies = 'http://localhost:3001/'
const axiosServer = axios.create({
  baseURL: url,
});

class EntertainMeController {
  static readEntertainMe(req, res) {    
    let movies;
    let tvseries;

    axiosServer({
      url: urlMovies,
      method: 'get',
    })
    .then(({ data }) => {
      movies = data;
    }

   res.status(200).json({
    movies
   })
 }
```

}

i write this code inside controllers, router.get('/', EnternainMeController.readEntertainMe)
movies is undifined, any help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
  static async readEntertainMe(req, res) {    
    let movies;
    let tvseries;

   let { data } = await axiosServer({
      url: urlMovies,
      method: 'get',
   })
   movies = data;
   res.status(200).json({
     movies
   })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding res.status inside of then block. Then block will be executed asynchronously from the main code flow.

Also if this helps, you can remove the movies variable.

```
axiosServer({
  url: urlMovies,
  method: 'get',
})
.then(({ data }) => {
  movies = data;
  res.status(200).json({
    movies
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One liner answer: Use *var movies* instead of *let movies*.

Explained: It is an issue of lexical scoping which can be handled using closures. You need access to outer function scope. A closure is the combination of a function bundled together (enclosed) with references to its surrounding state (the lexical environment). In other words, a closure gives you access to an outer function’s scope from an inner function. In JavaScript, closures are created every time a function is created, at function creation time.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures